# How can i cancel backgroundworker operation after reporting 5% to the progress changed event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the dowork event i did:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            var root = Convert.ToString(e.Argument);  // txtHost.Text;
            searched_until_now_dirs = 0;
            total_dirs = 1;
            max_percentage = 0;
            last_update = DateTime.Now;
            directories_real_time = new TreeNode();
            var dirNode = CreateDirectoryNode(root, "root",1);

            e.Result = dirNode;
        }
```

Then in the progressChanged event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
            this.toolStripProgressBar1.Value = Math.Min(this.toolStripProgressBar2.Maximum, e.ProgressPercentage);
            label11.Text = numberOfFiles.Count.ToString();
            if (e.ProgressPercentage == 5)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
            }
        }
```

First it never get inside if it's 5 it's keep going on. Never get to the CancelAsync line.
I want that after 5% of the job it will be cancel and get to the completed event.

This is where i'm doing the progress report inside the CreateDirectoryNode method:

```
private int total_dirs;
        private int searched_until_now_dirs;
        private int max_percentage;
        private TreeNode directories_real_time;
        private string SummaryText;

        private TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(string path, string name , int recursive_levl )
        {
            var directoryNode = new TreeNode(name); to its Tag

            var directoryListing = GetDirectoryListing(path);

            var directories = directoryListing.Where(d => d.IsDirectory);
            var files = directoryListing.Where(d => !d.IsDirectory);

            total_dirs += directories.Count<FTPListDetail>();
            searched_until_now_dirs++;

            int percentage;

            foreach (var dir in directories)
            {

                directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(dir.FullPath, dir.Name, recursive_levl+1));


                if (recursive_levl == 1)
                {
                    TreeNode temp_tn = (TreeNode)directoryNode.Clone();

                    this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker( delegate
                    {
                        UpdateList(temp_tn);
                    }));
                }


                percentage = (searched_until_now_dirs * 100) / total_dirs;
                if (percentage > max_percentage)
                {
                    SummaryText = String.Format("Searched dirs {0} / Total dirs {1}", searched_until_now_dirs, total_dirs);
                    max_percentage = percentage;
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(percentage, SummaryText);
                }
            }

            percentage = (searched_until_now_dirs * 100) / total_dirs;
            if (percentage > max_percentage)
            {
                SummaryText = String.Format("Searched dirs {0} / Total dirs {1}", searched_until_now_dirs, total_dirs);
                max_percentage = percentage;
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(percentage, SummaryText);
            }

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                TreeNode file_tree_node = new TreeNode(file.Name);
                file_tree_node.Tag = "file" ; // you can put here any object you want..

                directoryNode.Nodes.Add(file_tree_node);
                numberOfFiles.Add(file.FullPath);
            }



            return directoryNode;
        }
```

Comment: after 5% means `if (e.ProgressPercentage >= 5)`, not `== 5`

Comment: There are several problems. 1)You're not calling `backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress`, in which case `ProgressChanged` will not be fired at all. 2)You're not handling the cancellation anywhere. 3) Checking for exact percentage is the wrong thing to start with, you probably need `if (e.ProgressPercentage >= 5)`

Comment: Right forgot to add the CreateDirectoryNode method where there inside i'm reporting the progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see you reporting the progress to the worker. The example below should cover your case.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
    }

    void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
        if (e.ProgressPercentage >= 5)
        {
            worker.CancelAsync();
        }
    }

    void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
        while(!worker.CancellationPending)
        {
            // TODO: do something.
            // TODO: update percentProgress 
            // backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(percentProgress);
        }

        if (worker.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will actually *attempt* to cancel the work, instead of *immediately* stop it. The correct solution in this case is to use flags to stop it

Comment: codemonkey you right i added the method where i'm doing the reporting of the progress. I'm reporting it from inside the CreateDirectoryNode method.

Comment: codemonkey i tried to add the part of your solution in the progresschanged with the worker but still it dosen't enter when it's 5. I used a breakpoint and it keep going on never enter.

Comment: codemonkey i tried now it does enter and doing the worker.CancelAsync(); but it's never get after it to the completed event. The backgroundworker is keep working and the precentages i see getting larger and it keep entering the worker.CancelAsync(); but never realy stop the operation and get to the ecompleted event.

Comment: Dod you put a unit of work in the `while (!worker.CancellationPending)` loop? Every step in that while should do a very small part of the work and then report progress, otherwise the flag is never checked...

Comment: Check the worker.CancellationPending flag in your `CreateDirectoryNode` method and return when it's true. That'll stop your processing.